# Trying to fire onclick event asp:ImageButton

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer

My asp:ImageButton doest not fire onclick event on IE, but is working normally on chrome or firefox.

Don't know if my code is right, but is here:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="SaveBtn" runat="server" OnClick="Save_Click"
                 ToolTip="Save" ImageUrl="images/save.png" />
```

Using .NET Framework 3.5

**Note:** IE10

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code.  What *exactly* happens when it fails?  Which version of IE?  Is there a JavaScript error in the browser console?  Is the page posted at all?  How have you confirmed what's going on?

Comment: IE 10, no javascript code :(

Comment: It's *highly unlikely* that there's no JavaScript code in a WebForms page.  Look again.  You're going to need to do at least *some* debugging here, because the code you posted doesn't replicate the problem.

Comment: I just changed imagebutton to linkbutton and put image inside!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just install .NET Framework 4.5**

IE10 has a bug.

IE10 incorrectly convert coordinates to decimal rather than integer. This causes ImageButton clicks to fail.

You could try some workaround, like:

**- change the ImageButton to a LinkButton and put the button image inside of it.**

Your code will look like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="SaveBtn" runat="server" OnClick="Save_Click">
     <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/save.png" ToolTip="Save" />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Take a look [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/755419/asp-net-4-0-and-ie10-click-on-imagebutton-in-updatepanel-produces-error-click-on-normal-button-does-not) too.

Comment: I changed the imagebutton to linkbutton like you said. It Works!